# How do I reproduce this document theme?

Tags: titles, document-classes

It seems to me very similar to the default Beamer theme. I like it very much and wish to produce `article` with it too. What should I do to reproduce this?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the chapter heading style?

Comment: @HarishKumar yup! And I understand this is a book class. It would be wonderful if there is a article counterpart available.

Comment: In article, there is no chapter!

Comment: @HarishKumar yup that's true! So what I wish is just my article title has the same style as the chapter title, and my section titles are like those section titles. :)

Comment: Like this? http://i.stack.imgur.com/YPAcI.png

Comment: @HarishKumar The title is great, but the section title is a bit off. Do we have to modify these one by one? Is there a less hackish way whereby we can just invoke a class to achieve this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is not hackish at all. See my answer.

Comment: I don't understand the question, really.  Are there multiple instances of such *titles*?

Comment: @Johannes_B http://down.cenet.org.cn/upfile/28/20071110194334120.pdf

Comment: Sorry, this is even more confusing for me. What is the pdf? Your init-state? Your goal? It looks `report`-based.

Comment: @Johannes_B Sorry for the confusion! I took the screenshot from this PDF. It is a book, but my goal is to turn my `article ` into a similar style. :)

Comment: `article`s don't have chapters, as stated before by @Harish. And how can this be a screenshot of the linked pdf? Please make your question clear. Is your question: *How can i make sections look like chapters?* Or is it *I need an additional sectioning-level higher than section?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this may be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\normalfont\sffamily\Large}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{\color{DarkBlue}\sffamily\Huge Hypothesis Testing in \\ Linear Regression Models}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \section{Introduction}
  \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why using `\maketitle` here including formatting where it doesn't belong?